# Como pegar um texto de uma QLineEdit no Qt?

Tags: c++, string, qt

Por exemplo, eu tenho uma `LineEdit`, quando eu apertar um botão quero pegar o que eu escrevi nessa `LineEdit` e armazenar uma `QString`.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente o que você precisa é **criar uma função em seu programa para ser chamada toda vez que um evento de clique no botão for emitido**.

[image: Saída do programa]

Segue exemplo de código completo e comentado:

**QLineEdit.pro**

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = QLineEdit
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    //Toda GUI que utiliza QT precisa ter um objeto QApplication
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    //Cria a janela principal
    MainWindow *window = new MainWindow;

    //Exibe a janela principal
    window->show();

    //Basicamente impede que o programa termine e sua janela seja destruida    
    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <iostream>

class MainWindow : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QLineEdit *_QLineEdit;
    QPushButton *_QPushButton;

public:
    MainWindow();
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void my_slot();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow() {

    //Cria um layout
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);

    //Defini o layout de MainWindow
    this->setLayout(layout);

    //Aloca memória dinamicamente para o editor de linha, definindo MainWindow como seu pai
    _QLineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);

    //Adiciona o editor de linha ao layout
    layout->addWidget(_QLineEdit);

    //Aloca memória dinamicamente para o botão, definindo MainWindow como seu pai
    _QPushButton = new QPushButton(this);

    //Adiciona o botão ao layout 
    layout->addWidget(_QPushButton);

    //Conecta o sinal de botão pressionado ao slot que criamos
    QObject::connect(_QPushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(my_slot())); 
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
    /*
        Não há necessidade de adicionar instruções para liberar a memória alocada,
        pois isto será feito automaticamente uma vez que todos os objetos criados
        foram definidos como sendo filhos de MainWindow.
    */
}

void MainWindow::my_slot() {
    //Recupera o texto armazenado no QLineEdit
    QString myString(_QLineEdit->text()); 

    //Atribui o texto ao botão para testar
    _QPushButton->setText(myString); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Com QtCreator:** Crie um botão e um lineEdit. Daí faço uma ação para ele: go to slot -> clicked.

A partir daí só criar o comando. Lembrando que, para quem usa o Qt Creator, deve-se usar a ui pois os comandos devem ser acessados a partir dela. Se você não usa o QtCreator é altamente recomendado que o utilize para aprendizado.

**Trecho de JanelaPrincipal.cpp**

```
 void JanelaPrincipal::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    mString = ui->lineEdit->text();

    qDebug() << mString ;
}
```

e crie sua variável `mString` em `Janelaprincipal.h`, private se for utilizada somente na classe (geralmente o é). O QDebug acima é somente para teste de captura.

Poderia ser feito assim, mas você teria problemas de escopo, dependendo do uso:

```
void JanelaPrincipal::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString mString;

    mString = ui->lineEdit->text();

    qDebug() << mString ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

De forma genérica assim seria isto:

```
suaString = lineEdit->text(); //lineEdit é o objeto do editor
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Qt/GetTextLineEditor.cpp).

Comment: Basicamente é isso mesmo.